# Solder Mask Layer in PCB Design using Altium PCB

Tags: pcb, altium

I'm beginner in PCB design. I'm confused about solder mask layer in Altium.
I want to put solder mask layer to cover my via point as precaution step to avoid any short circuit. Did I have to set put layer in Altium before send to pcb manufacturer or just inform them without setting it at gerber file?

Comment: This link will take you to an excellent (and official) Altium resource: forum.live.altium.com

Comment: @Chris Knudsen - Your link didn't copy well, is this what you meant to include:  https://resources.altium.com/altium-live

Comment: @Chris Knudsen - Maybe this is better, here is the general Altium support page: https://www.altium.com/support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are asking about "tenting" your vias, where soldermask is applied over the via.  You can do this by:

1. Selecting your via (or all of them using the Find Similar Objects... dialog).
2. Open the via properties.
3. Scroll down to Solder Mask Expansion.
4. Click on "Manual," and then tick the boxes for tenting on top and bottom.
   [image]

Of course that is the manual way to do it.  You can also do the same operation from the Rules:
[image]

HOWEVER, simply setting this rule will override most all of your soldermask - including pads, which you don't want!  Therefore if you take the rules approach you'll want to create two rules: one for tenting vias, and one for everything else.  You can catch vias for the first rule by setting up a Custom Query with "IsVia."
[image]

Comment: Already test it. Correct. Thanks smith